# Adjust json file using ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json file with the following content

```
{
    "name":"myApp",
    "version":"1"
}
```

I would like to use Powershell to read this json file, adjust the version number, then output the new json to the same file.

I currently have this, but it doesn't work and only outputs an empty file

```
Get-Content file.json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach{$_.version = "2"} | ConvertTo-Json |  Out-File file.json -Encoding ascii
```

I am getting stuck on how to update values on the Json object created by ConvertFrom-Json and pipe this back into ConvertTo-Json

I would like to do this all in one line if possible.

Comment: You're missing the actual output: `ForEach { $_.version = "2"; $_ }`, assigning a value to a property does not produce any output. Also, `Get-Content` should be wrapped in `( .. )` or you will end up with an empty file: `(Get-Content file.json -Raw)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you assign the JSON to an object, you should be able to change it from there then write it to a file (if desired).

Create JSON object from file contents:

```
$jsonObject = Get-Content file.json -Raw |  ConvertFrom-Json
```

Change the current object. In your example the "version" property:

```
#update object
$jsonObject| %{$_.version = "2"}
```

Write object to file:

```
$jsonObject | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "file.json" -Encoding ascii
```